# Possible problem with wifi n standard

Tags: 12.04, wireless, iwlwifi

Hia all,

I have recently upgraded my internet connection, which included changing the wifi router. Since then, my wifi connection is somewhat shaky, works great sometimes, sometimes completely dead (usually around midnight! very strange...), and these kinds of problems. Everything works great when I use a LAN cable or connect, connect via wifi to other networks, or connect to this network from other devices.

I suspect that the problem might be related to the fact that I might have disabled my 802.11n wifi. It was some time ago and I don't quite remember what I did  (I asked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/448727/disable-802-11n-for-a-specific-network)). How would I check if I disabled the n standard, and how would I reverse it? Are there any other wifi diagnostic tools that might help me here?

Thanks

BTW, I'm running 12.04

**EDIT:**

Thanks for all the suggestions.

a) I don't have a `iwlwifi.conf` in `/etc/modprobe.d`. The result of `ls /etc/modprobe.d` is

```
alsa-base.conf               blacklist-watchdog.conf
blacklist-ath_pci.conf       dkms.conf
blacklist.conf               nvidia-304_hybrid.conf
blacklist-firewire.conf      nvidia-current_hybrid.conf
blacklist-framebuffer.conf   nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf
blacklist-modem.conf         oss-compat.conf
blacklist-oss.conf           vmwgfx-fbdev.conf
blacklist-rare-network.conf
```

b) The result of `lspci -nn | grep 0280` is

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 [8086:0887] (rev c4)
```

Comment: In fact, 11n_disable=0 in your previous post is the default. Adding the line does nothing. May we see: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Thanks.

Comment: Note that all wifi standards since "n" have used the 5GHz band exclusively, which will reliably work over a shorter range (though, with higher speed within that range).  If you need greater coverage from a single access point, through walls, etc, "n" on the 2.4GHz band is definitely likely to help.  That said, the 5GHz band is less "crowded" so neighbours' wifi is less likely to interfere with each other.

Comment: @chili555 I posted the results

Answer (score 0):

The first place I would look for parameters like those in the other post would be `cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` and then check what parameters you can use with `modinfo -p iwlwifi`  If you find that the cat command shows just `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1` you can delete the file `sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` and reboot

EDIT: Please add the result of `cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` to your question before using `sudo rm /etc/modprobe/iwlwifi.conf`

Comment: I didn't think the extra lines to automatically remove or add iwldvm/iwlmvm existed yet in 12.04

Comment: Quite correct. Sorry for my mis-step, @Jeremy31

Answer (score 0):

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, I have better luck with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

If these changes do not help, please try:

```
sudo -i
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
exit
```

Reboot and test.